# Хочу понять как работает рекурсивные функции на примере этого кода? Python

Tags: python

мой вопрос заклучаеться в том, как считать каждый последующий k+tri_recursion(k-1) ?
Когда пытаюсь зайти в этот код и считать каждый цикл просто заблуждаюсь, опытные люди скажите пжл как вы считаете эту рекурсивную функцию.
Спасибо

```
 def tri_recursion(k):
  if(k>0):
    result = k+tri_recursion(k-1)
    print(result)
  else:
    result = 0
  return result

print("\n\nRecursion Example Results")
tri_recursion(6)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

это сумма арифметической прогрессии до k с шагом 1

т.е. функция вычисляет `6 + 5 + 4 + ... + 1`

как работает функция -

функция складывает значение аргумента со значением функции, чей аргумент на 1 меньше

функция при аргументе `0` возвращает `0`, а не вызывает очередную функцию, поэтому на `0` рекурсия остановится

рекурсию можно представить так:

```
F(6) = 
6 + F(5) = 
6 + 5 + F(4) =
6 + 5 + 4 + F(3) =
....
6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + F(0)
```

и как писал выше на F(0) рекурсия обрывается

это кстати частая ошибка - забыть условие обрыва рекурсии, каждый вызов функции - это запись в стек, поэтому если рекурсия не разрывается, то стек переполняется и возникает ошибка

P.S.

кстати данную функцию можно было бы записать в 1 строчку:

```
def func(k):
    return (k + func(k - 1)) if (k > 0) else 0
```

или через лямбда-выражение:

```
func = lambda k: (k + func(k - 1)) if (k > 0) else 0
```

Comment: Супер, спасибо большое!!!