# Рекурсивная задача Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, рекурсия

Решаю питон задачку. Условие:

> Implement the sum_positive_numbers function, as a recursive function
> that returns the sum of all positive numbers between the number n
> received and 1. For example, when n is 3 it should return 1+2+3=6, and
> when n is 5 it should return 1+2+3+4+5=15.

Так же мне дан примерный код под эту задачку:

```
def sum_positive_numbers(n):
  return 0

print(sum_positive_numbers(3)) # Should be 6
print(sum_positive_numbers(5)) # Should be 15
```

Я пробовал решить так:

```
def sum_positive_numbers(n):
  for i in range(n):
     n += i
  return n
print(sum_positive_numbers(3)) # Should be 6
print(sum_positive_numbers(5)) # Should be 15
```

Всё решается так, как нужно и вывод тот же..
Но мне выходила ошибка:
Here is your output:
6, 15. Not quite. While the result can be achieved without
recursion, we want to use recursion for this exercise.
Я не понимаю как построить тут рекурсивное решение.

Comment: данный вопрос уже был вчера: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1209893/%d0%a5%d0%be%d1%87%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-python/1209898#1209898

Answer (score 1, accepted):

примерно вот так

```
def sum_positive_numbers(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return sum_positive_numbers(n - 1) + n
```

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, цикл должен стартовать с единицы и заканчиваться n `for i in range(1, n):`, во-вторых, это совсем не рекурсивное решение

Можно, например, так:

```
def sum_positive_numbers(n):
   return 1 if n == 1 else n + sum_positive_numbers(n-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_positive_numbers(n, s=0):

    if n == 0:

        return s

    s += n

    n -= 1

    return sum_positive_numbers(n, s)

print(sum_positive_numbers(6))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]